# how to read each element of an yaml map

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am trying to access all the elements of a yaml object, any suggestions would be helpful:

```
object:
  element1: "value1"
  element2: "value2"
  element3: "value3"
```

The above object is defined in group_vars/all file so that it can be accessed by other tasks.

```
- name: pass values to script
  debug: "msg={{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ object.element1 }}"
    - "{{ object.element2 }}"
```

Now this method allows me to accept each element but i want to get this done so that all elements in the object (irrespective of the number of objects) is read by the with_items. I tried the following:

```
- name: pass values to script
  debug: "msg={{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ object }}"
```

But this considers the entire object as one item. Any suggestions on how i could get all elements into the list with_items:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution for the problem was to use with_dict.

```
- name: pass values to script
  debug: "msg={{ item.value }}"
  with_dict:
    - "{{ object }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:
     with_items: object

It works for inventories definition.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, the suggested solution simply prints the word object, it doesn't event identify that its an yaml object.